# Non-Standard Derived Equivalences of Non-Flat Algebras

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, morita-equivalence, morita-theory

I read that for algebras $R$ and $S$ (over a commutative ring), assuming that $R$ or $S$ is *flat*, the existence of a derived equivalence $\mathcal{D}(R) \to \mathcal{D}(S)$ implies the existence of an $R$-$S$-bimodule complex $X$ s.t. the derived tensor product $- \otimes^{\mathbb{L}}_R X \colon \mathcal{D}(R) \to \mathcal{D}(S)$ is a triangulated equivalence (cf. 3.1 and 3.2 [here](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~bernhard.keller/publ/pap.dvi), Theorem 3.13 [here](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/schwede/glasgow.dvi)).

Is there an example of two (non-flat) algebras which are derived equivalent, but for which no such bimodule complex exists? Or is there a proof of this kind of "Morita theorem" without the flatness assumption?